# handle listview with button

Tags: android, listview

i have a listview and button on the list how can i use both button.setonclicklistener and onListItemClick in listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the button.setOnCLickListener in your getView() method of the adapter.

Comment: How will it help listening to button events? Your answer should be unticked.

Comment: Probably you should give it a try before commenting. I guess the person who asked the question did try it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.But while adding button's onClick event to adapter,it was not able to listen to the list item's click event.so I used image instead of a button and then registered its click event in adapter,and that was working nicely.

Comment: The only significant difference between a button and an image is that button takes focus while image doesn't. You could set android:focusable=false on the button and it would work either.